# Ayuda con Lista De Personas y Ficheros JAVA

Tags: java

Antes que nada decir que soy nuevo en esto de la programacion , y que me disculpo por mi ignorancia y mi falta de vocabulario, y por tanto los problemas que pueda ocasionar.

A partir del fichero “personas.txt”, estoy intentando desarrollar un método, en el cual se recorra dicho fichero y luego se me compare una de las propiedades de las personas que aparecen el fichero (en este caso es el apellido1), con la correspondiente cadena que le proporciono al metodo, para que luego esas personas que coinciden con dichos apellidos (apellido1), se me devuelvan en una lista.

personas.txt:

```
Javier#Medina#Rodriguez#42269273b#170#M

Ana#Baez#Rodriguez#76543219ab#168#F

Marcos#Garcia#Andres#22222222a#192#M

Pancho#Rodriguez#Perez#33333333b#166#M

Echedey#Zamora#Sanchez#66666666y#182#M

Daniel#Trujillo#Avila#59123658d#177#M

Andrea#Medina#Rodriguez#25781113b#158#F

Juanma#Leon#Santana#12345678j#183#M
```

Metodo:

```
public ArrayList<Persona> ficheroListaPersonaExamen (String rutaFichero, String primerApellido) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    ArrayList<Persona> listaPersona= new ArrayList<Persona>();
    BufferedReader fichero =new BufferedReader(new FileReader(rutaFichero));
    String registro;
    Persona persona;

    while((registro=fichero.readLine()) != null) {
        String[]campos=registro.split("#");
        if(primerApellido.equals(campos[2])) { //ME DICE QUE EL FALLO LO TENGO EN ESTA LINEA
            persona = new Persona(campos[0], campos[1], campos[2], campos[3],
                    Integer.parseInt(campos[4]), campos[5].charAt(0));
            listaPersona.add(persona);
        }
    }
    fichero.close();    
    System.out.println("Fin del la lectura del fichero");
    return listaPersona;    
}
```

Llamada:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Preparacion prep = new Preparacion();

    try {
        System.out.println(prep.ficheroListaPersonaExamen("ficheros/personas.txt", "Medina"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException");
    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException");
    }

    System.out.println("FIN DEL PROGRAMA!!!");
```

Clase Persona:

public class Persona {

```
public String nombre;
public String apellido1;
public String apellido2;
public String DNI;
public int altura;
public char sexo;

public Persona(String nombre, String apellido1, String apellido2, String dNI, int altura, char sexo) {
    super();
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido1 = apellido1;
    this.apellido2 = apellido2;
    DNI = dNI;
    this.altura = altura;
    this.sexo = sexo;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido1() {
    return apellido1;
}

public void setApellido1(String apellido1) {
    this.apellido1 = apellido1;
}

public String getApellido2() {
    return apellido2;
}

public void setApellido2(String apellido2) {
    this.apellido2 = apellido2;
}

public String getDNI() {
    return DNI;
}

public void setDNI(String dNI) {
    DNI = dNI;
}

public int getAltura() {
    return altura;
}

public void setAltura(int altura) {
    this.altura = altura;
}

public char getSexo() {
    return sexo;
}

public void setSexo(char sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
}
```

}

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Por favor, revisa [ask]. En concreto ¿podías explicar el problema que te has encontrado?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías solucionar tu error identificando si la linea leída es diferente de un salto de linea. Añadiendo una condición al while.

```
while((registro=fichero.readLine()) != null && (fichero.readLine()) != "\n") {
    String[] campos=registro.split("#");
    if(primerApellido.equals(campos[2])) { //ME DICE QUE EL FALLO LO TENGO EN ESTA LINEA
        persona = new Persona(campos[0], campos[1], campos[2], campos[3],
        Integer.parseInt(campos[4]), campos[5].charAt(0));
        listaPersona.add(persona);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como muestras el archivo texto, estoy pensando que vienen unos renglones con información y luego pueden venir unos renglones sin información. Necesitas revisar cuando lees cada línea si tiene o no información. Si no tiene, te la brincas:

```
 /**
   con este método puedes revisar si tiene el apellido que buscas
   y si es un renglón en blanco no genera excepción
 **/
 public boolean contieneApellidoBuscado(String[] campos, String apellido) {
     return (apellido != null
             && 
             campos != null
             &&
             campos.length > 2
             &&
             campos[2] != null
             &&
             apellido.equals(campos[2]));
 }
```

Luego una parte de tu código:

```
while((registro=fichero.readLine()) != null) {
    String[]campos=registro.split("#");
    if (contieneApellidoBuscado(campos, primerApellido)) {
        persona = new Persona(campos[0], campos[1], campos[2], campos[3],
                Integer.parseInt(campos[4]), campos[5].charAt(0));
        listaPersona.add(persona);
    }
}
```